# Issue knitting to a pdf document using gganimate (animation not included)

Tags: r, pdf-generation, r-markdown, knitr, gganimate

I am trying to generate a pdf document that contains an animated plot using the gganimate package. I am following Thomas Lin Pedersen [example](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thomasp85/14ed997191f7c6d363517a4dd89f090b/raw/83f47cd81631bfa10e69dfea92bb3e2c661c4fc1/pdf_animation.rmd):

````
---
title: "PDF Animation Test"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{animate}
---

`gganimate` now supports animations inside PDF documents. This feature is only 
viewable with Acrobat Reader, however. Remember to include 
`\usepackage{animate}` in the preamble and set `fig.show='animate'` in the chunk
options. Further, the framerate is governed by `interval`rather than any 
`gganimate` settings:

```{r, fig.show='animate', interval=1/10}
library(gganimate)
ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp, group = Month)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  transition_reveal(Month, Day)
```
````

When I knit to a .pdf and I read the document with Acrobat Reader, the pdf does not include the animation. This is the output that I get after knitting the document:

```
processing file: pdf.Rmd
  |................................                                 |  50%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.................................................................| 100%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 2
 $ fig.show: chr "animate"
 $ interval: language 1/10

executing: ffmpeg -y -r 10 -i pdf_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-1-%d.pdf -b:v 1M -crf 10 pdf_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-1.webm
ffmpeg version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
pdf_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-1-%d.pdf: No such file or directory

/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS pdf.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output pdf.tex --template /home/atai/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' --variable 'compact-title:yes' 
output file: pdf.knit.md


Output created: pdf.pdf
```

At the beginning, I thought it was an issue with my pandoc version which was version 1.19.2.1, so I updated it to version 2.3.1; although, this did not solve the problem.

Information on my session:

```
~$ pandoc -v
pandoc 2.3.1

sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Thomas forgot to mention that this feature requires the development version of **knitr**:

```
devtools::install_github('yihui/knitr')
```